# React-native creating library "null is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativeStartappAds.default.showMessage')"

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to create new library for react-native project. I started to create library with only show toast message to learn how to create and use it, but I still get an error when I use it in my react-native project.

I have created new library;

```
react-native-create-library --package-identifier com.startappAds --platforms android startapp-ads
```

and I modified in RNStartappAdsModule, than I published my library on npm, after publish I install the library on my project. I can import the library, but when I want use function on library it gives me error.

Here is my RNStartappAdsModule;

```
@ReactMethod    
public void showMessage() {
      Toast.makeText(reactContext.getApplicationContext(), "NATIVE CODE IS WORKING", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

how I use it my project

```
import RNStartappAds from 'react-native-startapp-ads';

_showNativeMessage() { RNStartappAds.showMessage(); }

<View style={converterWrapper}>
     <Button title="Show Native Message" onPress={() => {SearchMusic._showNativeMessage()}}/>
</View>
```

It should show me toast message from native sdk but I get an error like this.

> null is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativeStartappAds.default.showMessage')

Comment: try to `console.log(RNStartappAds)` and check whether the showMessage function is present or is undefined

Comment: @AnkushRishi function returns undefined.

Comment: @AnkushRishi do you have any idea to why my function is not present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After create library, link to project.

```
    react-native link react-native-startapp-ads
```